# Phonegap how to sign an app with google play store key

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

Ok, i build up an android app with phonegap, now i want to sign my app. The thing is that the google play store gives me an License Key but i dont know how to use it. Because Phonegap ask me for an "title" "Alias" and a keystore file. Dut was is meant with the title the Alias and the keystore file? I mean i only got one code that should work like an key.

Answer (score 4):

The key that Google Play Store provides you is for use in their License Verification and in app purchase libraries. To publish your app, you need to use a  keystore file, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done, using a Windows system.

1) Download Java for Windows [link here](https://www.java.com/en/download)

2) Set your computer's environment variables to have the path to the keytool.exe e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;%path%

3) Run the following command, replacing the items in square braces with the appropriate names e.g. MyApp and MyAppAlias

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

4) Give a password and answer the questions. Write down the password someplace safe.

5) I am using build.phonegap so I upload the .keystore file in my account and use the password(s) to unlock it. Then I can select it when building.